# What is hardware trap?

Tags: operating-systems

Since it's called a trap I consider it caused by software, so why it's called a hardware trap? And how does it work?

[image: hardtrap]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_(computing)

It is called a hardware trap because the mechanism of triggering it, and handling it, is embedded in the hardware itself and it cannot be [fully] controlled/disabled in software.